# reference to a temporary and warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I've lost one hour to find this problem in my code:

```
vector<string> & input_variables = parse_xml(xml_path)["variables"];
```

where `parse_xml` is a function returning a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >`. Why gcc is not warning me (with -Wall)? Am I missing some flags?

Comment: [Insert advertisement for `valgrind` or similar tools]. No but really, it will pay for itself in time saved learning to use them ;).

Comment: Please can you list your complete compilation flags. Specifically your Warning flags

Comment: Shouldn't the lifetime of the temporary be prolonged as 12.2/5 suggests?

Comment: @sharptooth: Nope. Lifetime extension does not apply because the result of `operator[]` is not an rvalue.

Comment: @sharptooth And it doesn't refer to a temporary, but rather to some dynamically allocated memory in `std::map`.

Answer (score 2):

You have taken a reference to an object which is destroyed. In C++11 new language features are written in making this code illegal. You must make a copy or swap the data into a local variable if you wish to use it. GCC is not warning you because C++03 does not provide the necessary features to prevent such.

Technically, the return value of `operator[]` is an lvalue. Unfortunately, it is about to be destroyed by it's owner, the `std::map`.

Comment: Are you sure that this would be invalid in C++11? The problem here really is that the return of `parse_xml` is a temporary but not a constant object.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: In C++11, you can overload member functions- including `operator[]`- based on lvalue or rvalue. This means that `operator[]` can return a temporary- correctly preventing this code. `const` has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: @DeadMG: So is it a defect report that the standard containers do not use this feature in C++11 to prevent dangling temporary references?

Comment: @NicolBolas: They don't? That's absolutely a defect. That's practically the whole reason for introducing the feature in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

GCC doesn't warn you because technically there's nothing to warn about.

`parse_xml()` returns a `std::map` by value, which is a temporary. Calling `operator[]` returns a reference. The compiler cannot know *locally* that this reference is actually *part* of the `std::map` temporary. For all the compiler knows, `operator[]` could be returning a reference to a global or something.

A member variable of a temporary is considered a temporary, which is linked to the lifetime of the outer temporary. But the return value of a function (like `operator[]`) is *not* so linked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't warn you is because you are getting an invalid operation through a sequence of valid steps:

```
struct X
{
    int c;
    int & operator [] (int) { return c; } /* this is perfectly OK */
};

X f()
{
    return X(); /* this is perfectly OK */
}

int main()
{
    int &x = f()[1]; /* can apply [] on temporary, therefore OK */
}
```

You can prevent this from occurring by explicitly marking the result of `f()` as `const`.

Comment: `const` rvalues are bad. They can't be moved from, for example.

Comment: ANSI? ANSI never Standardized any version of C++. There is only ISO C++- the current version of which was Standardized last year.

Comment: @DeadMG The original C++ standard C++98 is commonly referred to as ANSI C++. And usually, when someone is referring to ANSI C++, he usually means the ISO standard from 2003.

Comment: Well, he's very wrong. There is only ISO C++. That is C++11. But `const` rvalues are bad even in C++03.

Comment: @DeadMG Actually he isn't. If I remember my C++ history correctly, the standardization process started at ANSI, then moved to ISO, the name stayed.

Comment: @DeadMG And there even is an ANSI C++ group in the standardization committee (didn't know that). http://www.gotw.ca/iso/